# Recursive string reversal function in javascript?

Tags: javascript, recursion

I'm a pretty experienced frontend engineer with a weak CS background. I'm trying to get my head around the concept of recursion. Most of the examples and purported explanations I can find just aren't explaining it in a way I find easy to understand.

I set myself a task of writing a function that will reverse a string recursively. I know there has to be a base condition (i.e. the solution is found), but I can't figure out how to actually write something like this and could use a demo to study.

Could someone provide a sample function?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Something like:

```
function reverse (str) {
    if (str === "") {
        return "";
    } else {
        return reverse(str.substr(1)) + str.charAt(0);
    }
}
```

So the function is recursive as it calls itself to do the work.

Comment: As straightforward as it gets.

Comment: Thanks. This is really easy for me to understand. I'm next trying to see if I can manually reverse an array recursively.

Comment: The array version will be much trickier because arrays in ECMAScript (of which JavaScript is an implementation) are purely imperative...

Comment: This is what I did for reversing an array: var x = function(arr){

    if( arr.length === 1 ){
        return arr;
    }else{
        return x( arr.slice(1) ).concat(arr[0]);
    }

}

console.log( x([1,2,3,4]) );

Comment: Nice demonstration. FYI, to reverse a string, you wouldn't need recursion: [somestring].split('').reverse().join('') would do the same ;)

Comment: @Koolinc Yeah, I know. This was simply so I can get my head around recursion.

Comment: `slice()` is preferrable to `substr()`: it's standardized in the ECMAScript spec and works uniformly cross-browser.

Comment: I have a correction to this. In a case you've described, it takes +1 recursion iteration to finish a job. If you change "if" statement to: "if(str.length === 1) { return str; }", it will take exact number of operations as length of string is without additional run to return a blank string result. But in this case each time str.length will be called. I need to benchmark this :)

Comment: Here is my benchmark showing performance difference: http://jsperf.com/recursive-string-revert. Also use of .substr() over .slice() is a bit faster at least in Chrome.

Answer (score 4):

A tail recursive version, just for kicks (even though JavaScript doesn't perform tail call elimination):

```
function reverse(str) {
  function r(s, acc) {
    return (s.length == 0) ? acc : r(s.substr(1), s.charAt(0) + acc);
  };
  return r(str, '');
};
```

Comment: what do you mean with *even though JavaScript doesn't optimize*?

Comment: Many compilers/interpreters perform [tail call elimination](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call) (some language specs even require it) which makes tail-recursive functions perform comparably to their iterative counterparts.  The ECMAScript specification has no such requirement and no existing JavaScript interpreters do it, as far as I know.

Comment: in ES6 spec, tail calls are properly interpreted now.

Answer (score 1):

One line of code using boolean operators.

Explanation: if string exists call the recursion to reduce the string, otherwise fallback to non existing string (last recursive call)

```
  function reverseString(s) {
    return s && reverseString(s.slice(1)) + s[0] || s;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

A 25% faster function: [jsperf.com](https://jsperf.com/recursive-string-revert2)

```js
function Reverse(str) {
  if (str === null) {
    return null;
  }
  if (str.length <= 1) {
    return str;
  }
  var first = str[0];
  var last = str[str.length - 1];
  var str1 = Reverse(str.substring(1, str.length - 1));
  return last + str1 + first;
}

var result = Reverse("a really serious string of nothingness making call stack to explode");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function reverse(str) {
  if(str.charAt(0) === ''){
    return "";
  }
  return str.charAt(str.length -1) + reverse(str.substring(0,str.length-1));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

//call this function with the string as parameter

```
function strrev(str) {
    return str.length !== 1 ? strrev(str.slice(1))+str[0] : str;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr), you should use [`substring()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) instead of [`substr()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr):

> Warning: Although `String.prototype.substr(…)` is not strictly deprecated (as in "removed from the Web standards"), it is considered a **legacy function** and should be avoided when possible. It is not part of the core JavaScript language and may be removed in the future. If at all possible, use the [`substring()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) method instead.

Additionally, if no index is provided as a parameter to [`charAt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charAt), the default is `0`.

Therefore, we can write a recursive one-liner to reverse a string using a [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) and by applying the logic described above:

```js
const reverse_string = s => s === '' ? '' : reverse_string(s.substring(1)) + s.charAt();

console.log(reverse_string('Hello, world!')); // !dlrow ,olleH
```

Answer (score 0):

The base case that I am using for exiting the recursion is when the the length decrease to 0

On each recursive call we will take out the last character of the string and append it with the result that we will get from recursive call of a string, which is smaller in size as the last character is removed using slice.

```
function reverse(str){
 if(str.length===0)
    return "";

return str[str.length-1]+reverse(str.slice(0,str.length-1));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this code below for simple reversal of strings through recursion

```
const reverseIt = (x) => {
    if (x === "") {
      return "";
    }
    return x[x.length - 1] + reverseIt(x.substring(0, x.length - 1));
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I solved it:

```
function reverse(s) {
  const index = s.indexOf(" "); 
  if(index === -1) {
    return s
  }
  else { 
      return reverse(s.slice(index+1)) + " " + s.slice(0,index)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution:

```js
function reverse(str, newStr = "") {
  // Base case
  if (str.length === 0) return newStr;
  // newStr += str.slice(-1)
  return reverse(str.slice(0, -1), newStr += str.slice(-1));
  }
  
  console.log(reverse("house")) // esuoh
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution using default parameters:

```js
function reverse(str, newStr = "") {
  // Base case
  if (str.length === 0) return newStr;
  
  return reverse(str.slice(0, -1), newStr += str.slice(-1));
  }
  
  console.log(reverse("house")) // esuoh
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let fruit = "APPLE";

function reverseStringByRecursion(name) {
  if (name.length == 0) {
    return "";
  } else {
    let lastChar = name[name.length - 1];
    let excludingLastChar = name.slice(0, name.length - 1);
    return lastChar + reverse(excludingLastChar);
  }
}

var reversedString = reverseStringByRecursion(fruit);
console.log("Reversed string:", reversedString);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
function recurse(s) {  
  if (s.length == 0) {  
    return '' // stopping condition  
  } else {  // return last char + result of function called with chars up to last char  
    return s.substring(s.length, s.length -1) + recurse(s.substring(0, s.length -1))  
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

So far the best I think:

```
function reverse(s) {
    if (s.length===1) return s;
    return reverse(s.slice(1)) + s[0];
}
```

Answer (score -3):

It is verbose, but I like making it easy to understand in logical steps:

```
function rev(soFar, count){
   console.log("asString: " + soFar );
   console.log("count: " + count);
   var len = soFar.length;
   var ret = soFar;//ret needs to be a reference to soFar
   if(len > count){
      var subd = soFar.substring(1,len);
      var first = soFar[0];
      //we want to inject the first letter at the index position one back from the length, minus what the count is at this point
      var indexOfInsert = len-1 - count;//so if count is 0 and length is 5, we want 4 (4 -0)
      var asArray = subd.split("");
      asArray.splice(indexOfInsert,0,first);
      count++;//need to increment count for the next round
      var asString = "";
    //recreate as string, not array - the default toString() makes this a comma delimited string. It is best toi just recreate it in a loop
    for(var i = 0; i<len; i++){
        asString+=asArray[i];
    }
    ret = rev(asString,count);//ret always needs to be reassigned
}
//only get here when count is greater than the length of the original string
return ret;//will always be a reference to soFar, which is being reassigned in the recursive loop
```

}

Then call it like:

```
var reversed = rev("Hello",0);
console.log("result",reversed);
```

Answer (score -4):

This is a pretty straightforward C# implementation of the algorithm you asked for. 
I think it could be rewritten in javascript pretty easily.

```
/*
C#: The Complete Reference 
by Herbert Schildt 

Publisher: Osborne/McGraw-Hill (March 8, 2002)
ISBN: 0072134852
*/


// Display a string in reverse by using recursion. 

using System; 

class RevStr { 

  // Display a string backwards. 
  public void displayRev(string str) { 
    if(str.Length > 0)  
      displayRev(str.Substring(1, str.Length-1)); 
    else  
      return; 

    Console.Write(str[0]); 
  } 
} 

public class RevStrDemo { 
  public static void Main() {   
    string s = "this is a test"; 
    RevStr rsOb = new RevStr(); 

    Console.WriteLine("Original string: " + s); 

    Console.Write("Reversed string: "); 
    rsOb.displayRev(s); 

    Console.WriteLine(); 
  } 
}
```