# Reverse String in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I wrote a JS constructor which reverse a string variable:

```
function ReverseString(string) {
    this.str = string;
    var size = this.str.length;
    this.reverse = function () {
        for(size; size >= 0; --size) {
            console.log(this.str[size]);
        }
    }
}
```

When I invoke a reverse method on a new string object(`"asd"`) it produces the following output:

```
  undefined 
    d 
    s 
    a
```

Where this `undefined` came from? Could you help me eliminate this ?

Comment: The range of characters indexes in a string goes from zero to the string length, **minus one**.

Comment: Also, just in case you don't want to reinvent the wheel, `str.split("").reverse().join("")` is an useful idiom.

Comment: Just curious, any particular reason you're inventing an entirely new type of object `ReverseString` with a single purpose in life which is to reverse the string it holds? You plan to reverse it again and again?

Comment: Let's see, you searched for "reverse string javascript" before posting this question and found nothing, I guess. Seems no-one ever had this problem before. Except http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1611427/reversing-a-string-in-javascript, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4859208/recursive-string-reversal-function-in-javascript (see duplicate answer below), and off-site resources such as http://eddmann.com/posts/ten-ways-to-reverse-a-string-in-javascript/.

Answer (score 6):

The `length` problem is already explained. To solve it you could use:

```
function ReverseString(string) {
    this.str = string;
    var size = this.str.length;
    this.reverse = function () {
        while(size--) {
            console.log(this.str[size]);
        }
    }
}
```

Another (more simple way) to reverse a string is to split it into an array, reverse that, and join again:

```
somestring.split('').reverse().join('');
```

Applied to your method, something like this snippet:

```js
const result = document.querySelector('#result');
const RString = stringFactory();

// constructor
const myReversed = new ReverseString('hello world');
myReversed.reverse();

// factory
result.textContent += ` | `;
RString(`Hello World`).printReversed(result);

function ReverseString(string) {
  this.str = string;
  this.reverse = function() {
    const rev = this.str.split('').reverse();
    rev.forEach(v => result.textContent += v);
    this.reversed = rev.join('');
  };
}

// factory pattern
// see also https://github.com/KooiInc/es-stringbuilder-plus
function stringFactory() {
  return str => assignHelpers(str);
  
  function assignHelpers(str) {
    return {
      get reverse() { return str.split('').reverse().join(``); },
      printReversed(elem) {
        str.split('').reverse().forEach( l => 
          elem.textContent += l );
      }
    };
  }
}
```

```css
#result {
  letter-spacing: 0.5rem;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```

To circumvent the problem [@Mark Baijens](https://stackoverflow.com/users/443523/mark-baijens) commented on (combined Unicode characters, aka surrogate pairs), a modern solution (es20xx) could be:

```js
const str = `foo  bar mañaña`;
document.querySelector(`#result`)
  .textContent = [...str].reverse().join(``);
```

```css
#result {
  letter-spacing: 0.5rem;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: Warning: This implementation will not work with combined Unicode characters. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16776380/443523) post for an explanation about this.

Answer (score 2):

At the beginning, `size` is going to be 3 (the length). There is nothing at index `3`, hence `undefined`. You need to initiate it at `length-1`.

```
var size = this.str.length - 1;
```

Comment: I think a better idea would be to either fix the condition in the loop or give the variable a different name. I don't like the idea of a variable named `size` which isn't *actually* the size (length) of the string.

Comment: I agree that `size` isn't the best name, but names aren't the most important thing. The logic is. Good names help though, of course.

Comment: A variable called `size` that isn't actually the *size* of something sounds pretty illogical to me.

Answer (score 2):

Try as altenrative

```js
[...str].reverse().join``;
```

In your solution `size` at beginning should be `length -1`. You mix string reversing with string printing, but you can separate it as follows

```js
let str = "Hello World!";
let r = [...str].reverse().join``;
console.log(r);
```

Answer (score 2):

## Here are three ways to reverse a string in javascript

Iterate through string in reverse order and push letters to array, then join the array

```
function reverse1(str) {
  if(!str || str.length < 2 || typeof str !== "string") {
    return new Error("Not a valid input");
  }
  const backwards = [];
  for (let i = str.length; i > -1; i--) {
    backwards.push(str[i]);
  }
  return backwards.join('');
}
```

Use split, reverse, and join methods

```
function reverse2(str) {
  return str.split().reverse().join();
}
```

Use ES6 arroe function and spread operator to copy as well as convert the string to array and then reverse and join

```
reverse3 = str => [...str].reverse().join('');
```

Call the three functions

```
console.log(reverse1("Hello World!"));
console.log(reverse2("Hello World!"));
console.log(reverse3("Hello World!"));
```

#### Output

```
!dlroW olleH
Hello World!
!dlroW olleH
```

Comment: `reverse2` (as even your Output shows) doesn't work because you haven't specified arguments for splitting and joining. `function reverse2(str) { return str.split().reverse().join(); }`

Answer (score 2):

What about this easy step

```
"hello world".split(' ').map(word=>word.split('').reverse().join('')).join(' ')
```

it will reverse every word in its place

```
"olleh dlrow"
```

Comment: You seem to have left out the actual reversing step: `"hello world".split(' ').map(word=>word.split('').reverse().join('')).join(' ')`

Answer (score 1):

User recusrsivity, easiest way to do it

```
function reverse(str){
     if (str.length == 0){ 
        return '';
     }
     return reverse(str.slice(1)) + charAt(0);
}
```

Comment: Instead of `str.substring(1, str.length)`, just `str.slice(1)`. You're also missing parens around your `if` clause.

Comment: I don't think the OP was looking for an alternative implementation but was rather asking why their implementation gave some unexpected results.

Comment: Thanks, changed :) I'm doing delphi at the moment used to write with no parens x)

Comment: @MattBurland Yup, just giving another solution faster to write. recusrsivity can be usefull :3

Answer (score 1):

I would use `reduceRight`:

```
function sum(arr) {
    return arr.reduceRight(function(result, chr) {
        return result += chr;
    });
}
```

Now I have a handy routine I can also use to sum up sequences of numbers (in reverse order, but that doesn't matter).. For string:

```
function reverse_string(str) {
    return sum(str.split(''));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In here you have get the size of the 'string' constructor parameter and you decrese the length of the given word('size' variable).

```
function ReverseString(string)     { 
    this.str = string; 
    var size = this.str.length;
    this.reverse = function () {
        for(size; size >= 0; --size){ //loop from index value 3 to 0 
          console.log(this.str[size]);
        } 
    }
}
```

But the problem is when you input      word 'asd', the length of that string is 3.   So, when you access the index of str[3]   should be undefined. Because,

```
    index[0] --> a
    index[1] --> s
    index[2] --> d
    index[3] --> undfined
```

So, your code should change,

```
function ReverseString(string)   { 
    this.str = string; 
    var size = this.str.length; 
    this.reverse = function () {
        for(size; size > 0; --size) { //loop from index value 2 to 0 
            console.log(this.str[size - 1]);
        } 
    }
}
```

So, output should be like this,

```
    index[0] --> a
    index[1] --> s
    index[2] --> d
```