# What's wrong with following code for string reverse in javascript?

Tags: javascript

```
function stringReverse(str){
    return str.split('').reverse().join('');
}
```

In an interview, i was asked to reverse a string. I solved it by above code but my interviewer said this is a bad solution. Then i used loop but he was not happy.

```
function stringReverse(str){
    var a = str.split(''), b=[];
    for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
       b.push(a[a.length-1-i]);
    }
    return b.join('');
}
```

Please add your comments.

Comment: Probably because it can’t properly handle characters that are longer than 1 byte.

Comment: I would read this - https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-reverse-a-string-in-javascript-in-3-different-ways-75e4763c68cb. Seems you are doing nothing "wrong". perhaps ask the interviewer what their issue is :)

Comment: how was your loop then?

Comment: My guess is that he has a self-perceived good answer in his mind - although it's not so good.

Comment: As pointed out here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5276953/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-reverse-an-array-in-javascript
the **reverse()** function is the culprit here and is said to be slowest.

Comment: Depends on the length of the string. A fairly short string (<64 chars) then a loop us quicker, anything longer and your method is quicker. I see nothing wrong with your approach.

Comment: @Xufox Please write any string , which characters are longer than 1 byte.

Comment: @MDAAQIBJAWED e.g. a string containing an emoji.

Comment: @MDAAQIBJAWED `"Easy: "`

Comment: Well interviewers most of the time don't want you to blindly solve a problem. But to  recognize possible problems, and to clarify the use case and boundary conditions. So did you ask what the input to `stringReverse` could be and what kind of strings it should be able to handle?

Comment: @t.niese It was simple 'abcdef'.

Comment: @MDAAQIBJAWED Did you ask if it would always be that simple? Could the function get `null` or `undefined` as input, and should it handle that case and if so how? Should it deal with multi-bytes, ...? Did you ask anything about where it will be used and if there are any other requirements to that function?

Answer (score 4):

May be interviewer wanted you to handle `null`, `undefined` or `blank` string

without this check your code might throw this exception

> Cannot read property 'split' of undefined

use this :

```
if( str) {
str.split('').reverse().join('')
}
```

will evaluate to true if value is not:

- null
- undefined
- NaN
- empty string ("")
- 0
- false

OR more specifically :

```
if( str && (typeof str == 'string') ) {
   // do something
}
```

refer this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5515349/1531476) for more details.

Comment: May be best to explicitly test for a string:  `if(typeof str == 'string')`.  Otherwise, an error would be thrown if the value is an object, number, etc.

Comment: That will be more precise agree :) however this will work well for reasonable values.

Answer (score 1):

There are two possible ways your interviewer might not have been happy with your answer.

1. From my experience, when an interviewer asks you to reverse a string, you shouldn't use the existing functions for it. You should implement it from scratch. In your case, a nice approach would be to use recursion to solve the problem. [Look at this link!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4859208/recursive-string-reversal-function-in-javascript)
2. Performance issues! Using the reverse function is not the fastest way to reverse a string. [Check this out!](https://jsperf.com/js-array-reverse-vs-while-loop/5)

Hope this solved your questions :)

Comment: Recursion for such a function? I'm pretty sure that this would not be something the interviewer was looking for.

Comment: Yes, recursion. This is a very common interview question where the interviewer wants you to use recursion for this sort of problem. This would be O(log n).

Comment: If the interviewer explicitly asks for recursion, then maybe, but even then I would be suspicious, and ask why a recursive function should be used. I most surly would be shocked about a recursive solution for this task, if I wouldn't have asked explicitly to solve it with recursion or in a uncommon creative way.

Comment: Yeah, I understand where you're coming from. But speaking from my experience, the "best answer" for a string reversal is using recursion.

Comment: I think the best answer is walking the array, either copying to a new array or swapping in place.  The OP's answer is wasteful because of all the allocations.

Answer (score 1):

This article deals with unicode symbols in JavaScript: [JavaScript has a Unicode problem · Mathias Bynens](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-unicode)

The best solution to your problem uses the [Array.from](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) method which works in all browsers except from Internet Explorer (MDN has a polyfill for that).

Here is a solution based on the articles answer to reverse a string:

```js
function strReverse(str) {
  //Only allow numbers and strings to pass, else return empty string
  if (typeof str != 'string' && typeof str != 'number') {
    return '';
  }
  //Return the reversed string
  return Array.from(str.toString()).reverse().join('');
}
//TESTS
console.log([
  strReverse(),
  strReverse(null),
  strReverse("null"),
  strReverse(true),
  strReverse("▼ ▼▲ ▼"),
  strReverse(1138),
  strReverse(''),
  strReverse('fff'),
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

In ECMAScript 6, you can reverse string like as below

```
var string = "hello";
var str = [...string].reverse().join('');
console.log(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

When I was in 10th standard, Our computer teacher always asks every student to write a code to check if the given string is palindrome or not.

**Palindrome string is a string which is always same as its reverse ex: mom = mom**

In an interview, if someone asked you to write a code to reverse a string. Then he wants to see your logical approach to solve the problem. Existing function in any programming language has also code which actually put a logical approach and solves the problem.

Reverse code in java

```
import java.util.*;

class Reverse
{
  public static void main(String args[])
{
   String original, reverse = "";
   Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
   System.out.println("Enter a string to get reverse");
   original = in.nextLine();
   int length = original.length();
   for ( int i = length - 1; i >= 0; i-- )
     reverse = reverse + original.charAt(i);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String words[] = str.split("\\s");
    String rev = "";
    for (String w : words) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(w);
        sb.reverse();
        rev += sb.toString() + " ";
    }
    System.out.println("\n reverse string=" + rev);
```

Comment: This might be correct, but it's in `java` while the question was about **javascript** unfortunately.

Comment: oh yes !! i dint notice that yu need in javascript..Lemme try for it, come back.

Comment: Still working on that?

Comment: no Casey, did not get time to work on it. But I see people have already worked on it and given an answer.